# How to differentiate exponentials of operators?

Tags: operators, differentiation, commutator

Suppose we have 
$$e^{At}e^{Bt}=F(t),$$ where $$A, B$$ - operators that do not commute.
Now I need to take the derivative $$dF(t)/dt.$$ In which order do I write the operators?

$$dF(t)/dt = Ae^{At}e^{Bt} + e^{At}Be^{Bt}$$
or
$$dF(t)/dt = e^{At}Ae^{Bt} + e^{At}e^{Bt}B~?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the same, since any operator commutes with its exponential
\begin{align}
Ae^{tA} &= A\left(1+tA+\frac{1}{2!}t^2A^2+\dots\right) \\
&= A+tA^2+\frac{1}{2!}t^2A^3+\dots \\
&= \left(1+tA+\frac{1}{2!}t^2A^2+\dots\right)A \\
&= e^{tA}A
\end{align}
(and, in general, any operator $A$ commutes with every function $f(A)$ of it, for similar reasons).

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Cosmas Zachos' comment
Suppose $G(x)$ is some function which has an expression as a Taylor series.

$G(x) = \sum_i g_i x^i$

It can be proven* by induction that

$$
[X,G(X)]=0
$$

This means $[X,e^{Xt}$]=0$

In particular

$$
Ae^{At} = e^{At}A
$$
$$
Be^{Bt} = e^{Bt}B
$$

so both of your expressions are equal. What is important is to take care that you don't swap any terms involving $A$'s with any terms involving $B$'s.
The answer may have been more complicated.

*At least in a physics usage of the word..

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!